# 555 square wave generation with frequency feedback

Tags: 555, feedback, control-theory

Knowing that 555's behaviour varies according to temperature, I wondered:

In an astable configuration, is there some way to measure output frequency, compare it with some desired value, and use this to change the resistance in the config? (Basically a feedback loop)

This would be very useful, to create precision square wave generators.

I'm sorry if I couldn't explain myself correctly (the question sounds really bad when I read it but I'm struggling to express it correctly).

Comment: If you already had a precise way to measure the frequency you probably wouldn't need the 555 to begin with. Using a crystal oscillator, possibly with temperature control, is the way to get a precise square wave.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson makes sense, but what about frequencies that are not "standard" in xtals?

Comment: There are better ways to make a controllable square-wave oscillator than using a 555.  If you *did* want to use a 555 in a phase-locked loop, you can control the frequency by varying the comparator threshold (CONT on [this TI datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/na555.pdf)), and then follow the timer with a divide-by-two circuit to get a nice 50% duty cycle square wave.  Or, just use a 74xx4046 chip, or one of any number of similar parts.

Comment: You can use a phase-locked loop to derive various frequencies from a stable reference. You might also be interested in "direct digital synthesis", or DDS.

Comment: You can supply additional current across the resistor,  by  a current mirror that is controlled b a frequency detector,. You are building a servo loop, and proper loop gain & phase enter the picture,

Comment: @analogsystemsrf seems legit, how can I do that??

Comment: @IakaNoe what Tim said: if you want *anything remotely stable*, a 555 is not your tool. Go for an XTAL-based PLL or synthesizer IC. That's what everyone uses in the real world to generate frequencies.

Comment: What analogsystemsrf is how we did thinks in the 1970s when there were no DDS chips yet. Now we would just get a DDS, the AD9850 is affordable and there are modules with that chip with an interface you can hook to a uC. Trying to use a 555 based oscillator and "stabilize" it simply isn't worth the effort.

Comment: Also: if you want to learn about "precision square wave generators" then do some research into the subject. How many designs use a 555? **ZERO**. Says enough. The 555 is nice and very useful but not for anything precise.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I've yet to find a use case where the NE555 is "nice and very useful". I keep coming across things that can be nicely explained by using a 555, but not a single application that wouldn't be easier to prototype at lower part and usually way better performance using the cheapest microcontrollers. But, alas, Iaka *knows* the 555, which is imho it's main strength: it's a nice introduction for many many people to analog electronics!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Indeed I should have written "The 555 is nice and very useful **for beginners to get started with electronics without any programming**". The 555 is also nice to explain the basics of IC design (get the free ebook from: http://www.designinganalogchips.com/ ). Sure a uC is a better choice for a product but I see far too many people thinking that making a blinker with a uC is "real electronics" while they're basically just programming a uC.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Actually this question comes from me trying to reduce costs by changing my good old uC for a 555 to generate a carrier signal (and it failed)... I knew there were other ICs to achieve the same result but they were bigger (I'm making a really small PCB for a particular project) and more expensive.

Comment: Then next time, **properly** list your requirements (frequency, freq. stability etc) and ask for **ideas**. Now **you** steered the answer in the "NE555" direction which you now know, is a dead end, failing on frequency stability. For mass production there are uC that cost 3 cents (US$, see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYhAGnsnO7w&t=5s ), you can **never** beat that with a 555 solution.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie it's ok, I didn't ask this question to solve my "cheap and small" problem... I'm saying it came from that, but my question is out of curiosity

Comment: @IakaNoe sounds like you'd want to change your "good ol MCU" for a cheaper one plus a DDS, or synth, or for a MCU that has a better integrated PLL to give you high-frequency square wave outputs trough the very boring use of timers. What is your current uC?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm really ok with my wee uC. I just thought it's kind of a waste of money and overkill. I'm using a PIC12F683 with the ccp output.

Comment: Not overkill. Well, you can get cheaper than that 1€ microcontroller and still have a microcontroller. If you go for overstock of nicer microcontrollers, you might also get a cheaper microcontroller that does a lot more, including one that has an internall PLL that can generate higher frequencies than its external crystal has, and then you can use the timers to generate arbitrary fractions of that.

Comment: I think y'all really missed the point. I'm asking about 555 with feedback, not for advice on precise square wave generators...

Answer (score 1):

> In an astable configuration, is there some way to measure output frequency, **compare it with some desired value**, and use this to change the resistance in the config? (Basically a feedback loop)

Sure, thats relatively easy, but it requires that you have **something to compare it to**
Ie. to check whether your output signal is actually let's say 100kHz, then you need a signal which you already know IS definitely 100kHz, and if you already have that then why create it in the first place using a 555 circuit?

All absolute measurements come from comparing the thing that you are measuring to a known standard. In the case of for instance multimeters measuring a voltage they will have inside them a voltage reference, which has a well known, well defined voltage across it which you can compare the voltage that you are measuring to.

In the case of a frequency counter it will have a well defined frequency standard inside it which generates a constant well defined frequency which you can compare the frequency that you are measuring to.

Comment: But maybe you get a numerical value or some other output type when you measure the frequency and compare it with its desired value... For example, measuring the frequency using a microcontroller and comparing it that way.

Comment: ????? You realy dont seem to understand the point i am trying to make. the only way to get a numerical value representing the frequency of the output of your 555 is to compare it to a known frequency. In the case of a microcontroller what you would use to compare the frequency to would be the clock frequency og the mcu.

Comment: never denied that... Still not answering my question

Comment: Okay then I don't understand your question."But maybe you get a numerical value or some other output type when you measure the frequency and compare it with its desired value..." How would you get a numerical value representing the frequency? well you could count the number of periods, but then you still need to divide the number of periods by the time you count them over, so in other words we are back to the fact that you still need an accurate source of timing, ie. a frequency standard, in order to measure a frequency.. I am not sure you understand what my answer is about.

Comment: then give me some method to achieve that lol, in my example I would compare it with the timer of my uC but I was looking for some (maybe analog) method

Comment: Okay sure, the analog methon would basically be to turn your 555 into a PLL (phase locked loop), you would need a crystal oscillator (or other precise source of a clock), a programmable counter/ down divider, a phase comparator, and some way of adjusting the frequency coming out of the 555 circuit, for instance a FET replacing the resistor in the RC circuit. Look up PLL and learn about how that is done, then perhaps afterward you will appreciate that this is something that requires a masters degree in electrical engineering to do, and not something that I can guide you through in a comment

Comment: wow I did not expect such a mean answer... That's why I'm asking...

Comment: @IakaNoe That was not a very mean answer, that was a sign of well controlled frustration after 3 earlier answers that did explain the situation in different ways to try and get the message across.  A simple thank you and undertaking to research the suggestions would gain you more knowledge, humility and respect.  However you are free to solicit terse and frustrated answers if you like whatever label you achieve in the minds of others.  You need a better reference to compare against if you want to correct your 555 and this reference could replace the 555 in pretty much any expected situation.